# How to combine a kleisli with a conditional

Tags: scala, scalaz

Given an existing method f

```
def f : Kleisli[Future, Context, Seq[Tip]] = ???
```

I need a combinator that will use f depending on a conditional.
Here is my current impl :

```
def g(selected: Seq[Tip]) = 
    if (selected.isEmpty) 
      f 
    else 
      Kleisli[Future, Context, Seq[Tip]] { _ => Future.successful(selected.maxsBy(_.creationDate))}
```

Is there a better way ?

(the part that *lift* a single value into a `Kleisli` is quite verbose)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a shorter way to lift the `Seq[Tip]` into your `Kleisli`: you can use `ask` and `map` :

```
import scalaz.Kleisli
import scalaz.std.scalaFuture._
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

Kleisli.ask[Future, Context] map ( _ => selected.maxsBy(_.creationDate))
```

You can also convert a `Context => Seq[Tip]` to your `Kleisli` :

```
import scalaz.syntax.std.function1._

((ctx: Context) => selected.maxsBy(_.creationDate)).kleisli[Future]
```

Comment: Another solution : Future(t).liftKleisli